# Reload div with jQuery (file not found)

Tags: jquery, html, reload

I have this script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script  type="text/javascript"> 
var updateGallery = setInterval(function() {
$('#gmap2').fadeOut('fast').load('map.php').fadeIn('fast');}, 10000);
</script>
```

that needs to load file (map.php).

i have this line of code in the index.php page;

```
<div id="gmap2"> <?php include 'map.php'; ?></div>
```

In firefox error console i got Network error 404 File not found (http://domain.com/map.php)
Even if i put full url path to map.php file i got same error.

Thanx for help

Comment: Your question is unclear. 1) Where is located your javascript ? 2) Why  do you mention a server side include of a php file ? 3) If you have a 404 error, this is the obvious issue with your JS loading the file, can you give us something else about this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information here to give you an answer, but here's the first place for you to look:

Your http server log (and the HTTP error log) should show the URL (and hence the file) that your script is trying to fetch. Watch that relative URLs are resolved with respect to the resource (the file) containing them.

Depending on your hosting service and/or Web server, these might be in a subdirectory of where you log in with ftp or ssh; on my system they are in /var/log/httpd/error_log and/var/log/httpd/access_log (thes ecan be large files if the server is busy!).

It helps to have a window up running "tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log" when you are doing AJAX development.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, i found this in my error_log:PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'map.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/simple/public_html/wp-content/themes/960bc/index.php on line 140

Comment: What directory is map.php in on the server?

Comment: domain.net/wp-content/themes/960bc, same as theme and index.php. It is theme root directory